# Are open graph tags considered structured data?

Tags: structured-data, open-graph-protocol

I've heared that open graph tags are part of microformat which are a structured data.

But Google says [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data#using-meta-tags):

> We do not support variants of the META tag, such as the use of property instead of name.

Does it mean the open graph tags with the "property" attribute are ignored when Google analyize the page's structured data?

Comment: Looking at the update date of the page you liked to, I would take Google at it's word.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would say that Google do not view this within what they class as Structured Data from both what they say and also for the fact that this does not show within the Structured Data section of Google Search Console. However, I would still include open graph tags on all sites utilising social media etc.